# How to decrease the font size of mode-bar/line?

Tags: emacs

After horizontally splitting my frame into 4-5 windows, the info in the mode-line gets truncated. So is there a way to decrease its font size like I do in a buffer so that its text doesn't get truncated?

Comment: You might also be interested in libraries like [diminish.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiminishedModes) to abbreviate (or remove entirely) the minor mode 'lighter' text in the mode line, and hence improve the threshold at which this becomes a problem. The DIY method is to manipulate the `minor-mode-alist` variable directly. See also http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2010/05/cleaning-up-mode-line.html

Comment: @phils good suggestion but not of much help because info like column number, time, vc, buffer-name, coding system etc are not diminishable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use <kbd>M-x</kbd>`set-face-font`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`modeline`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and select the font you like. For some fonts, you might need to specify the size on the 7<sup>th</sup> place.

```
-microsoft-Georgia-normal-normal-normal-*-8-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1
                                          ^
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do this, for instance

`(set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil  :height 60)`

Substitute 60 for the height you want.  You may use hooks to change the value dynamically depending of some conditions, but afaik all the mode-lines will share same font.

Comment: It works, but only in active buffer. In ex. when you have two open bufffers on split screen ,mode line on not active buffer have default font size.

Answer (score 5):

You can type `M-x customize-face RET mode-line`, and set the height attribute.

Comment: This is by far the easiest way if you're not familiar with all the different settings. It also allows you to quickly save the change permanently or just for a single session.

Comment: @Yossarian true but the only downside, to me, is that you don't get suggestions in it for the font family etc, while you do so in case of choroba's answer